# neo4j cypher how to get rid of duplicate in count

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to find out how many times the actor are acting together, for example both Keanu and Carrie act in matrix, when I count it, it shows up two times, one for keanu, Carrie, the other is carrier, keanu. How do I get rid of 1 of them. I have create the example here http://console.neo4j.org/r/9p5798

Comment: +1 for posting sample at Neo4j Console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
START a=node(*), b=node(*) 
MATCH a-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-b 
WHERE id(a)< id(b) 
RETURN a, b, count(m)
```

Comment: Nice comparing `ID`, hadn't thought of that. But I don't think you should bind all nodes twice in the start clause (try dropping the `b=node(*)` and compare the execution plan).